# Difference quotient with cube problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, cubics

I'm studying for a test and I came across this problem in the review and I'm getting a different answer than the answer key

$$f(x) = x^3 - 4x$$

Difference quotient: $\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$

I'm getting the answer $h^2 + 3h + 7$ but the answer key says $-1+3h+h^2$

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you get for $f(1+h)$?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have made an error with a negative sign.

$f(x) = x^3 - 4x \\
f(1) = 1^3 - 4 \times 1 = -3 \\
f(1+h) = (1+h)^3 - 4(1+h) = (1 + 3h + 3h^2 + h^3) - (4 + 4h) = h^3 + 3h^2 - h - 3 \\
f(1+h) - f(1) = h^3 + 3h^2 - h \\
(f(1+h) - f(1))/h = h^2 + 3h - 1$

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is only about the constant term, you can consider
$$
f'(1)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\dfrac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=3\cdot 1^2-4=-1
$$
without further calculations. You have probably made a sign error in the first term.